# How to automate editing HTML/CSS in browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I want to edit two specific lines in some websites, automatically after loading. I want to edit `<div class="1">` to  `<div class="1" style="display:none">`, and `<div class="2" style="display:none">` to `<div class="2">`. The part to edit will be the same, on the sites, but i can´t say in which line, so it needed to be searched. It doesn´t matter, if this happens before or after the page loaded. I looked at Tampermonkey and Stylus, for example. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an effort and provide some code, then ask a more specific question. We're not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this snippet.

```
// Gets all elements with className 1 given in quotes and takes the first element of that list by using [0]
const divOne = document.getElementsByClassName("1")[0];
changeDisplayOnElement(divOne);
//Similarly
const divTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("2")[0];
changeDisplayOnElement(divTwo);

//change the property display under style to none, if it's block 

function changeDisplayOnElement(element){
   element.style.display = element.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```